# How to throw exceptions in rest controllers

Tags: java, rest, exception

I want to throw an exception from the controller. How can I do that?

```
@RequestMapping(value = "user", method = RequestMethod.POST, headers = "Accept=application/xml, application/json")
public @ResponseBody
AppUserDTO registerUser(@RequestBody AppUserDTO userDTO) {


        return userService.registerUser(userDTO);

}
```

In this return it will throw an exception. Is there any kind of annotation I could use? How will the exception be passed to the client side as JSON?

Comment: My preference is to just read the HTTP response and Json directly.  The heck with all this object abstraction layer crap ;) IMHO...

Comment: Can we have a ResponseDTO which contains the exception details and AppUserDTO will extend the ResponseDTO.Then the return type of the controller will be ResponseDTO.I don't know whether this suits for the REST style.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You appear to be using Spring-MVC.  There exist a handful of exceptions which, by default, map to specific HTTP error codes.  You can find a list of these here:

http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-ann-rest-spring-mvc-exceptions

Any other uncaught exception you throw will result in a HTTP 500 response.

For a detailed answer on how to use Exceptions with Spring, I suggest you read the linked page in detail or google "Spring MVC Exception".